# Calculating turns based on heading using Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet containing information about the speed and heading of a vehicle. I want to write a code that detects a turn (speed greater than 0 and a change in heading), while also being able to set a difference between a turn and a slight change in heading (20.1, 23.4, 27.2 vs 20.1, 20.3, 19.8).

I'm not sure how to translate this into a macro/code. How can I use multiple criteria to search each row/set of rows to detect a turn, and how do I implement standard deviation (presumably) to differentiate between a real turn and a slight magrin of error?

Edit: I tried coming up with a loop that uses the average heading to find where a turn starts and where it ends, but either the code or my "formulas" aren't working properly.
This is the code:

```
Sub TurnDetect()

    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim TurnStarts() As String
    Dim TurnEnds() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim Avg As Double
    Dim Avgj As Double
    Dim numTurnStart As Integer
    Dim numTurnEnd As Integer

    numTurnStart = 0
    numTurnEnd = 0
    lRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 3 To lRow - 1   'The loop starts with 3 because the first two rows are the title and measuring unit
        If i >= 6 Then
            Avg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Range("C" & i - 3 & ":C" & i).Value
            If Avg + 2 > Range("C" & i + 1).Value Or Avg - 2 < Range("C" & i + 1).Value Then
                numTurnStart = numTurnStart + 1
                ReDim Preserve TurnStarts(numTurnStart - 1)
                TurnStarts(numTurnStart - 1) = "C" & i
                For j = i to lRow - 1
                    Avgj = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Range("C" & j + 1 & ":C" & j + 4).Value)
                    If Range("C" & j + 2).Value > Avgj Then
                        'keep searching for the end of the turn, aka next j
                    Else
                        numTurnEnd = numTurnEnd + 1
                        ReDim Preserve TurnEnds(numTurnEnd - 1)
                        TurnEnds(numTurnEnd - 1) = "C" & i
                        i = j
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hard to say without a specific example, but decide on a deviation, loop through the cells, save the values (array or a couple of variables) and compare them to each other using the formula for deviation.

Comment: My suggestion: Given the knowledge of how many data points are captured per second, we know the average driver takes at least 4 seconds to complete a right or left turn (up to 10 seconds if driving slowly). Using 4 seconds as a minimum, In any collection of data equivalent to 4 seconds of capture, if the heading changes are all positive or all negative then the car has turned. To account for imperfections, I would lower that requirement from 'all' to 90%. Additionally, once a turn has been identified, skip searching the next few seconds of data to avoid double counting the same instance.

Comment: To avoid the issue about lane changes or slight curves in the road. Raise the scrutiny on what counts as a positive or negative change. Maybe it only counts if the magnitude is over a certain threshold. Or maybe the turn is only counted if at least one data point within the collection reaches a specific total. Or the starting value must be X different from the ending value.

Comment: Lanes and curves aren't an issue here, the data in the sheet comes from single lane, perfectly straight roads. I tried coming up with some sort of loop to check where turns start/end based on the average of the last/next 4 cells, but that didn't quite work. Editing that code in shortly